# How to set SSL pinning using retrofit for Firebase Realtime Database Url?

Tags: android, firebase, ssl-certificate

I have Firebase Database link

this link as example
https://my-tempdb-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/db.json

In my android app I need some static parameters which are change only once in month so I did use firebase and getting response as json. I want to use as json not want to implement database library for fetch data cause this use in multiple apps so don't want to add google-service.json file for that so I did fetch response in json format.

```
{
    "wert": true,
    "kert": 1
}
```

I'm using this url as GET request in retrofit.
In firebase write rules are set as false. So no one can write but me.

**So My question is I want to pining to this url so no one can missuses this url with man in middle attack. How to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

I think to use Firebase Database might be a little overkill, considering that you don't want to use Database. Have you considered to use [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=android)? Remote Config is exactly suitable for your use case, also it's a great way to gate your new features, A/B testing, etc. But unfortunately you would still need to google-service.json to your app, honestly don't think you can avoid it.

Let me know if you found a way to avoid adding google-service.json to the app and have a secure access to it.

Comment: I know about this. That's what I want to avoid . But so back to my question cab I do pining with db url?

Comment: May I ask why do you want to avoid it? Are you planning to use Crashlytics, Analytics, PerfMonitoring all these can come for free with Firebase

Comment: Also FCM if you app is planning to receive push notifications

Comment: No sir We are not going to live our apk on playstore not going to use Any FCM service till near future. We can't afford new server and paid for that so we don't want to burden bill of someone just get url and missuse. But If not find any solution then we have to purchase server or use FCM remoteconfig.

Comment: I see, got it. Yeah, I'm not sure that there is way to do it without google-service.json . But if you find, please update the question. Super curious

Comment: of course sir I'll do